# Manage communication between two app using service and messenger

Tags: android, service, messenger

I want to develop two apps. I need an app able to start and stop a second app. To do this I set up a messenger between these two apps using a service. The service is sticked to the second app.

I initialized the intent like this in app1:

```
protected void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent();
    mIntent.setAction("com.package.service");
    bindService(mIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

} 
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

        mIsBinded=false;
        mServiceConnection=null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {

        mIsBinded=true;
        mMessenger = new Messenger(arg1);
    }
};
```

And I send a message to Close the app2.

In app2 I have a service like this:

```
public class RemoteServiceClient extends Service
{
static final int STOP = 0;
static final int CONTINUE = 1;
private static final String TAG ="service" ;

class MyHandler extends Handler
{

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what)
        {
            case STOP:
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("stop"));
                Log.d(TAG,"stopapp");
                break;
            case CONTINUE:
                break;
        }
    }
}
Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new MyHandler());
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

}
```

and I also put in manifest inside application:

```
<service android:name="com.package.app.service"
        android:process=":exported">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.package.service" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

In activity of app2 I put a braodcast receiver that when the message STOP is delivered the app calls finish() .

The problem I have is that the first time the messanger delivers the message and reboot the app2. Once app2 is reboot the app1 cannot be able to stop app2 again. I get this error:

```
05-04 15:47:28.168 16741-16755/com.package.app1 W/System.err: android.os.DeadObjectException
05-04 15:47:28.178 16741-16755/com.package.app1 W/System.err:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
```

Comment: if you want to send a "kill yourself" message to some other service use `startService` instead of binding to a service that will be killed right away

Comment: yes but my task is to send a kill yourself message to another app: app1 has to start app2 , kill it, do stuff and restart app2.

Comment: yes i know but there is really no difference

Comment: If there is an easier way I would to know it :) How I can use startService?

Comment: @Daniele i really need to something like this i need 2 apps communicate each other via Messenger. I have question can you check?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478498/how-to-send-remote-service-message-onclick-via-messenger